# distance of cone $C=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2=z^2, z\geq 0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose cone $C=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2=z^2, z\geq 0\}$ is given and I want to compute the distance of two points $p,q \in C$. Let $d_C(p,q) := \operatorname{inf}_{\gamma} l(\gamma)$ where $l(\gamma)$ is the length of the curve $\gamma$ in $C$ from $p$ to $q$.

How does one compute this length, explicitly?

---

Followings are my trial;

Let $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$ with $p_1^2+p_2^2=p_3^2$ and $q=(q_1, q_2, q_3)$ with $q_1^2+q_2^2=q_3^2$.

Let $\gamma$ be the curve $\gamma(0)=p, \gamma(1)=q$,  Then the length $l(\gamma) = \int_0^1 ||\gamma'(t)|| dt$.  Assume $\gamma$ is unit speed curve, then I can parametrize $\gamma(t) = X(u,v) = (u,v,\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$, then $l=\int\sqrt{E (u')^2 + 2 Fu'v'+ G(v')^2} dt $, then....

I think this approach is not good for computing $d_C(p,q)$. I wonder there is a better way to computing this distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The cone is a [developable surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface?wprov=sfti1), whose flattening is a sector of a disk. The length of a geodesic on a developable surface is the length of the line segment in its flattening.

Hence just compute the image of the two points $p,q$ in the flattened sector of disk and the distance between those in the plane. This distance is equal to $d_C(p,q)$.

Comment: This is not correct. Imagine two points on the cone close to the seam along which you glue the sector.

Comment: @TedShifrin  You have to define a sector that depends on the two points in order not to cross the seam. This is not an issue as the goal is just to compute the geodesic distance between two given points.

Comment: Well, your explanation needs to make this clear, eh?